# Passing camera image to another activity, nothing happens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera

What's wrong with my code? I sucessfully take the image, but the second activity is not starting. I want to pass my taken image to the second activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private Button buttonka;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        {
        buttonka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v){
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button: 
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, Uri mCapturedImageURI) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("data");
            Intent camintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            camintent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmapImage);
            startActivity(camintent);
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {

        Bitmap bitImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
        image.setImageBitmap(bitImage);

    }
}
```

Somehow the application is not reacting, and not starting the second activity, may I missed something? Hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your onActivityResult-  use `data.getExtras().get("data")`, not getIntent.  You don't want the intent used to launch the app, you want the one returned as a result.

Comment: Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras("data");
Intent cannot be applied java.lang.String

Comment: Sorry, forgot an extra get

Comment: No problem, I implented the code that you gave me, but the app is still not working properly after taking the picture the app drops me back to the main activity, it's looks like the onactivityresult somehow not starts

Comment: Well I see another problem-  image isn't set in your second activity (unless it is in code you cut to minimize things).  But this is probably a good time to use a debugger-  set a breakpoint in onCreate and in onActivityResult.  See that they're hit, or why they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution, forget to add the camera and write storage permission in the manifest files. If anyone get in a problem like this, make sure you writing the correct permissions! :) + removed the unused Uri mCapturedImageURI)